# wordpress allow directory php file browsing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have wp installed in my root directory(inside www folder) . Inside the root directory I also have created 'scraper' folder which has a couple of files inside it . When I go myblog.com/scraper/index.php it says not found . But I can access js and css files inside 'scraper' directory . I tried a couple of tricks in htaccess file from SO but no luck . This is what it looks like now :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are the file permissions set correctly for the files you cannot access?

Comment: permission is set to 777

Comment: Switch on logging `RewriteLog` (2.2) or `LogLevel` (2.4) and post, what mod_rewrite is logging for such a request.